# Do all triads keep their function when inverted?

Tags: chord-theory

Then I suppose another question would be, when you add the 7ths over the triads can those also be inverted without losing their harmonic purpose?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A super easy example is a I6/4 chord is often predominant.

This page lists just the functions of some 6/4 inversions:

http://academic.udayton.edu/PhillipMagnuson/soundpatterns/diatonicII/secondinv.html

The cadential 6/4 is probably the most obvious one to recall from music from the classical period. It is the I chord in second inversion. From the page linked above (emphasis mine):

> In spite of the fact that this chord resembles tonic (containing ^1 - ^3 - ^5), **in reality it has nothing in common with the tonic function to the ear**. It does not provide stability and, in fact, has a strong need to resolve to dominant.

Regarding seventh chords, one example I can find is that the third inversion of the dominant seventh chord is often resolved to the second inversion of the tonic, so that makes the third inversion of the dominant seventh no longer necessarily dominant.

*Inversion* of a triad specifically speaks to which note of the triad is the lowest sounding. If the root is the lowest sounding note, the chord is not inverted. The lowest to highest order of the other notes of the triad beyond the lowest sounding note is often called the *voicing* of the chord. I'm not aware of a change in voicing changing the harmonic function, but a voicing change can have a more melodic function.

Comment: Ok thanks and assuming that the bass is in the root position could you switch all the other notes as much as you like without any problems?

Comment: It may be helpful to note that many schools actually label this a V64, the logic being that the 6 and 4 above the bass are accented non-chord tones that resolve to the 5 and 3 above the bass, respectively. In this view, this chord isn't predominant, it's just dominant.

Comment: @Richard Then what is a V chord in second inversion called? (e.g., D G B in the key of C major)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Also a V64. But it's not as confusing as it may seem; context clarifies it. If it's at the end of a phrase, approaching a cadence, and it resolves to a V in 53 position, we know it's a cadential 64.